Entity Framework migrations error shown when publish ASP.NET Core 7 "dotnet tool install dotnet-ef the tool package couldn't be restored"
I am using .NET 7 and I can add migrations and ... successfully with EF Core and my project works fine. But when I want to publish the project, this error appears:

when I install dotnet-ef version 7.0.7 with command
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 7.0.7 

I don't know what the problem is.
Please help me - thanks in advance
